# Finding the limit of the following expression

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I evaluate:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow ∞} \bigg \{ \frac{n+3}{n+1}\bigg\}^n\quad ?$$

I know the answer is $e^2$, as this is a practice problem from a textbook. However I cannot understand how they got it.

Comment: The sequence written above seems to be the $\;n$- th power of the fractional part of $\;\frac{n+3}{n+1}\;$, and from the continuation of the question it obviously is not. Apparently it was meant to be $$\left\{\,\left(\frac{n+3}{n+1}\right)^n\,\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

Comment: You are right and the actual text book question is the one you wrote. But I just want to know how to find the limit of the expression, that is why I had written it that way.

Comment: @Timbuc: Somehow, I happen to see the curly brackets used as a substitute for the round ones, even in papers of big mathematicians.

Comment: @As I think we all understood what you want mainly from the "I know the answer is $\;e^2\;$" part, yet the expression still is wrong.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Can you give some examples? I have never seen that use **in this context** of sequences, though of course curly brackets can be used, and are used, as parentheses in many *other* cases.

Comment: @Timbuc: Of course if it is about sequences, you're right. I meant that often, where I (and many other people, I suppose) would use round brackets, I see curly brackets. (that is, just to contain an expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(1+\frac2{n+1}\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac2{n+1}\right)^{\dfrac{n+1}2}\right]^{\dfrac{2n}{n+1}}$$

The inner limit(set $\dfrac{n+1}2=m$) converges to $e$ as $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1m\right)^m=e$

Hope the limit in the exponent can be resolved easily.

---

Alternatively, $$\left(\frac{n+3}{n+1}\right)^n=\left(\frac{1+3/n}{1+1/n}\right)^n=\frac{\left[\left(1+3/n\right)^{n/3}\right]^3}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$

Comment: How does the inner limit converge to e?

Comment: @Asiful If you let $t=\frac{n+1}{2}$ you have $$\left(1+\ldots \right)^t.$$ Filling the dots and recognizing the behaviour of $t$ as $n\to\infty$ does the job.

Comment: I have understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as
$$a_n = \left(\frac{n + 3}{n + 1}\right)^n = \exp\left(n\cdot\ln\left(1 + \frac2{n + 1}\right)\right)$$

Now you can apply MacLaurin expansion to the logarithm:
$$\ln\left(1 + \frac2{n + 1}\right) = \frac2{n + 1} + o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

Thus
$$a_n \sim \exp\left(n\cdot\frac2{n + 1}\right) \to e^2$$